# An optimized algorithm or a method to find a multi word string (keywords) in a sentence (that has multi words)?

Tags: c, string, data-structures, pattern-matching, string-algorithm

I have a string (Hello this is a string) and i want to search a keywords in it. How shall i do it ?

I have to search the following keywords in a string:

String: Hello this is a string.

Keywords:
1. Hello this (should match)
2. Hello (should match) 
3. Hello t (should not match)
4. Hello this i (should not match)

Please suggest the optimised way to construct a data structure to store and search?

Answer (score 1):

If you're criteria is only the complete word should match not just half of it, use break when the character is not matching/ string has ended and string check whether the index+1 of the main string is a white space or comma or full stop or whatever as per your need. If it is then your string is exact match otherwise it will be a character.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for complete words in string. Add space after the keyword and follow these steps.

```
char * string = "Hello this is a string";
char * keyword = "Hello t ";

if(strstr(string,keyword) != NULL)
    printf("Matched");
else
    printf("Not Matched");
```

Comment: It doesnt work like that.Let me explain a bit what actually i need. I have a file having 1000 strings (first question how to store/construct a data structure so that there shall be fast searching) i.e "hello this is string 1", "Hello this is string 2". I want to search a keywords i.e (hello this, is string 3) 100 requests per seconds. Your soln will significantly drop the performance of an application if i would do strstr at every single request.If you have got any way to do it, kindly share or discuss.Also, if i have a string: "Hello" & i want to search a keyword="Hello". Your soln will fail.

Comment: In this case .. you can use trie data structure and insert every word of string as a node in trie.

Comment: I can not use trie data structure. Since the length of the keywords and a string is not fixed. Though trie searches in O(n), but as per above case; it will significantly increase search time. Another issue is, if i have 100 files then i will have to maintain 100 trie's which is not good from resident memory perspective. i hope you understand the challenges.

Comment: @Gurpreet  I do not understand "Your soln will significantly drop the performance of an application if i would do strstr at every single request." If you do not do some operation at every single request, how to calculate the result of every single request? you want a result cache mechanism to cache your previous results??

Comment: @Gurpreet Please edit question with your more detailed description in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Suffix tree can be an option. Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree